# How to transfer word references from one document to another?

Tags: microsoft-word

I finished writing my paper and I would like to format it in MLA style. I downloaded MLA template from Microsoft, and copy/paste the content from my old to the new document. Everything seems fine, except references. Although they appear in the text and at the end of the document in order, after updating them, they disappear completely.

In User/App Data/Roaming/Microsoft/Bibliography there is no Sources.xml file, so I can't import it in Word.

Any idea how to transfer the references?